# flutter i user persistent nav tab bar after return the tab main screen the problem was when return the tab screen at a time initstate not working

Tags: flutter, dart

The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
_Tab1ScreenState.dispose failed to call super.dispose.
dispose() implementations must always call their superclass dispose() method, to ensure that all the resources used by the widget are fully released.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: